# Which JDK should I use to compile my Android app with and which version?

Tags: android, performance, java

My question could break into two section:

1. I want to know if there is any downside to using OpenJDK instead of Oracle JDK,
   for example, if I compile my Android app with Oracle, would it be faster? If it would, is there any benchmark?  And in general what are the advantages?
2. Should I compile my app with OpenJDK/OracleJDK version 7 over 5? What are the differences?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- I want to know is there any downside for using OpenJDK instead of
>   Oracle JDK, for example, if I compile my andorid app with Oracle,
>   would it be faster?

Well AFAIK in Java, if you seek performance, go for OpenJDK, while those who want Reliability, favor Oracle's JDK.